# Active navbar link switching not working with jquery through addClass(), how would I go about fixing this?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get links on a navigation to be highlighted right when I scroll to a certain location on my webpage. To do this I have created a few variables to determine the scroll distance from the top of the page and to determine how far from the top of the page each section of my site is

On my navigation bar each link has the class of scroll which is used in the jquery code to find the offset of it from the top of the screen

My issue is with the bottom part of my jquery code where it says addClass and remove classes. the classes that I will add and remove determine if the link on the navigation bar are highlighted or not.

everything up until there works well, I just can't seem to figure out how to structure it so that it properly adds and removes each class from the links of my navigation bar

Here is my HTML page

```
    <body>

      <div class="container-fluid navigation fixed-top">
        <div class="row">
          <ul class="nav_tl col-lg-2">
            <img class="logotype" src="./images/logotype.png" enter code 
    herealt="whiteroom">
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <ul class="nav_bl">
            <li class="l1 Action1">
              <a class="scroll" href="#top">Home</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav_br col-lg-4">
            <li class="l1 Action">
              <a class="scroll" href="#about">About</a>
              <a class="scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
              <a class="scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

        <section class="hero" id="top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>top</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
    <section class="about" id="about">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>about</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>portfolio</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="contact" id="contact">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>contact</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </body>
```

and here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var scrollLink = $('.scroll');

  // Smooth scrolling
  scrollLink.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 2000 );
  });

  // Active link switching
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();

    scrollLink.each(function() {

      var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;

      if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation ) {
        $(this).addClass('Active');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('Active');
      }
    })
  })
})
```

currently when you scroll on my website the home link shows to be active but once you scroll past the home section it continues to stay active when it shouldn't be. The about, portfolio and contact section work well but when you scroll above the about section it also stays active when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a easy fix. If you try to `console.log()` the `sectionOffset` of the corresponding sections, you'll find, that it stays the same regardless of scrolling.

> The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element (specifically its border box, which excludes margins) ***relative to the document***.

The offset isn't influenced by the scroll state of the page at all. Fix:

```
var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()
```

This will basically calculate the position of the element relative to the browser window rather than the document itself.

---

Also note that

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('link-highlight');
```

Will cause you trouble since the home link and the other links aren't in one list and therefore no siblings. Consider moving them into the same list.